# Android apps total installs option is not showing on google play android app

Tags: android, google-play, publish

I have published my android app yesterday but neither total installs are showing on my android app google play page nor other people are able to search it on Google using my app name for example: if other people's app name is hello-app if they will search it on Google by "hello app Google play" it will show it on Google but when I am searching it using my app's name its not showing on Google. The thing is that people are downloading it, rating it, and writing review of it but still no downloads are showing [here is the link of my android app on Google play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lakshmi.mataji.eco&hl=en)

Comment: I think you need to wait 24 hours more.

Comment: Actually, at wat time did you upload it yesterday?

Comment: Sir i have uploaded at 1.45 pm yesterday and now current time is 2.40 pm

Comment: Normally, it will take a day to get the statistics displayed. In times, it may take few more hours. So, it will get displayed by today evening or tonight.

Comment: Thank you sir i am hoping the same by the way i have published an app first  time that's why i am taking little bit tension

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your statistics will show up but you need to be a bit more patient. Statistics are refreshed once a day so it may take over 24 hours for your first  statistics to display.

Ability to download your app is not affected so no need to worry.